# What's the advantages of git auto completion with bash?

Tags: git, autocomplete

I am reading the book "progit". It tells me that I can use auto completion script under bash.
But I'm not quite understand what benefit I can get from it.
Was it automatically push my local git change to a remote git sever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the purpose of auto-completion is to reduce the amount of typing that you have to do at the command line, thus saving you time and energy. When you enable Git auto-completion for your shell (such as Bash of zsh), many commands can be auto-completed for you by simply typing the first few characters of a command, then hitting the tab key to complete it.

For example, if you type

```
$ git chec
```

and then hit tab, auto-completion should complete the command as

```
$ git checkout
```

saving you the effort of typing the last 4 characters, `kout`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't care about Git auto-completion for a long time: the commands are short enough, and I created even shorter aliases for many of them.

But there are things you can't create aliases for, such as remote names and branch names, for example in these commands:

```
git fetch that-other-guy
git log that-other-guy/some-freakin-awesome-feature
git merge that-other-guy/some-freakin-awesome-feature
```

When collaborating with others, I like to use the same name for the remote of *the other guy* as his username on GitHub. Which can be long. In the past I used to be so lazy, if I had to do many operations on his remote, I would temporarily rename it to `x` to make it easier.

Similarly, feature branches are good to name in a way that captures their purpose, which can easily become a bit long, or sometimes even very long.

So after I played with the remote and branch name auto-completion in Git Bash where it's automatically setup correctly, I made sure to set it up in all my home systems as well ([here's my very recent article for doing this on a mac](https://coderwall.com/p/u7t9ha)).

So yeah, Git auto-completion totally rocks, I should have done it sooner.